# My code got stuck in a forever loop, how do I fix this?

Tags: python

My code:

```
answer = input("What would you like to say?")
answer2 = input("How many times?")
while answer2:
    print(answer)
```

The code should be working but when I type "I like trees" for variable: answer and "2" for variable: answer2, IT'S A FOREVER LOOP!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For one, `input` returns a string and you need an integer. Additionally, a for loop is more appropriate here than a while loop. Try the following:

```
for i in range(int(answer2)):
    print(answer)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's just saying "I lke trees".

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want it to say?

Answer (score 0):

A while loop needs some kind of *update*. You never update `answer2` so if it starts out as being true, your loop will never end.

Assuming `answer2` should actually be an integer.

```
answer = input("What would you like to say?")
answer2 = int(input("How many times?"))

while answer2:
    print(answer)
    answer2 -= 1
```

Integers are true as long as they are not `0`. Each time through we need to subtract `1` from `answer2` to bring it eventually down to `0`, at which point the loop will break.

---

Of course, negative numbers will also be true, and subtracting from a negative number will never get you to zero, so it's worth checking the user's input *before* the loop.

You might want to write a simple function like `get_positive_int` to provide this assurance that the user's input is greater than or equal to `0`.

```
def get_positive_int(prompt=''):
    while True:
        i = int(input(prompt))
        if i >= 0:
            return i
```